# Explanation for curved space

Tags: geometry

Can you please throw light on what is curved space and how can we understand that concept of curved space? I came across it while reading about Einstein's theory of relativity. I just want to understand how curved space looks like and how can I imagine it?

Comment: In the same way that we appear to be on a flat surface here on earth, when we are actually on something like a sphere - a curved surface - the idea of curved space is similar. There are lots of different "curved spaces," but the key is that we imagine space where the shortest distance between two points is not a line. For example, one view of gravity is a bend in space. I suspect this question will be closed as too vague, however.

Comment: Can you give an example of what area you are talking about? Are you think physics? Non-Euclidean geometry?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Einstein's theory of relativity uses Riemannian geometry, a non-Euclidean geometry where Euclid's fifth postulate and/or the usual metric is replaced by another axiom.

Postulate

> If a straight line crossing two straight lines makes the interior angles on the same side less than two right angles, the two straight lines, if extended indefinitely, meet on that side on which are the angles less than the two right angles.

Meaning if two lines are 'pointed' at each other, they will intersect.

Explanation of a metric space

> A set for which distances between all members of the set are defined. Those distances, taken together, are called a metric on the set.

Euclidean plane is a two dimensional real vector space that has an inner product. This can be extend to n-dimensions.

Now, with Riemannian geometries we have manifolds which are topological spaces which resemble Euclidean space. Intuitively this means a space which, when you are close enough to, looks like flat Euclidean space. Earth may appear flat, but it's not.

But we must be more specific. Riemannian geometry studies smooth/differential manifolds so that calculus can work. In calculus, we care a lot about tangent lines, and when a curvature is not smooth enough, i.e. it contains spikes, then the tangent line will not vary smoothly from point to point.

It is always good practice to see where these ideas came from. Think of geodesics -- straight lines applied to curved spaces, like latitude and longitude. With Riemannian metric, the geodesics are the shortest path between points, in their respective neighborhoods.